# Python assigning string format return value behavior is inconsistent

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, dictionary

When assigning a python string format return value like `'67.67.%s.%s' % (str(j), str(i))`, it is inconsistent between assigning to a key of a dict and assigning to a key in a sub-dict of a dict.

For example:

```
i = 0
j = 1
dict_template = {"id": "1", "another_dict": {"value": "hello"}}
dict_list = []
for idx in list(range(2, 1002)):
    new_dict = copy.copy(dict_template)
    new_dict['id'] = 'obj_id_%s' % str(idx)
    new_dict['another_dict']['value'] = '67.67.%s.%s' % (str(j), str(i))
    dict_list.append(new_dict)
    if i < 254:
        i += 1
    else:
        j += 1
        i = 1
```

In this example, every new_dict['another']['value'] would be the same string and have the same id. 
However, if I change this line `new_dict['another_dict']['value'] = '67.67.%s.%s' % (str(j), str(i))` to `new_dict["another_dict"] = '67.67.%s.%s' % (str(j), str(i))`, each new_dict["another_dict"] would have different values.

By the way I'm using Python 3.4.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`copy.copy` performs a *shallow copy* of the given argument. That means that it creates a new dict and adds to it references (not copies) to everything that was already in the first dict. For immutable things like strings and numbers, there's no problem. But each instance is pointing to the same (mutable) inner dictionary.

Instead, you need to use `copy.deepcopy`. It'll recursively create new copies for every attribute of the template argument.